# How to remove iframes by property name starting with from dom?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Using javascript (no jquery), I have a js file which adds some iframes to the page, looks like this in the dom:

```
<iframe name="_mozilla1" width="300" height="200"src="site.com"></iframe>
<iframe name="_mozilla2" width="300" height="200"src="site.com"></iframe>
<iframe name="_mozilla3" width="300" height="200"src="site.com"></iframe>
```

The end goal is to remove any `iframe` in the dom that has a `name` property that starts with `_mozilla`. Any idea how to accomplish this with  javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, like this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'))
  .forEach(function (el) {
    if (/^_mozilla/.test(el.getAttribute('name'))) {
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
  });
```